Как получить цвет пикселя экрана с помощью WinApi без скриншота
интернет.
У меня возникла потребность в получении цвета конкретного пикселя в окне другого приложения, не знаю важно это или нет, но я работаю с WindowsForms
Я изучил и русскоязычные, и иностранные форумы и узнал, что это делается через WindowsApi, но не смог найти нужный мне способ
Могли бы вы поделиться своим опытом или чем-то иным, подойдет даже чужая статья

возможные дубликаты

что значит без скриншота? почему? зачем?
